# RetrieveSalesforceObjects to retrieve Oppourtunity records

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need help with a journey which I have created. I have created a journey to send email on the basis of opportunity stage on an email field which exist in Salesforce opportunity.

I have used the following AMPscript code in HTML email template, but when final mail is coming up Opporunity name field which I have put in template stays empty.

My code:

```
%%[ var @rs

Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Opportunity', 'Id, Name,StageName', 'Name', '!=', 'abc')

]%%

%%=v(@Name)=%% //to print opportunity name
```

Thanks,

Praneet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you had just retrieved the salesforce object values and saved it in a list. You cannot directly display the values in the list. You would need to update your query as below

```
%%[ var @rs, @Oppname, @Opprow

Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Opportunity', 'Id, Name,StageName', 'Name', '!=', 'abc')

Set @Opprow = ROW(@rs,1)

Set @Oppname = FIELD(@Opprow ,"Name") 

]%%

%%=v(@Oppname)=%% //to print opportunity name
```

Refer to the [link](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/how_to_retrieve_account_information_by_accountid/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply! I used the above and modify to pull the Opportunity which is entering the journey but doing so I am getting Random Opportunity name in the template.

Here is the code look like

```
 >%%[ var @rs, @Oppname, @Opprow
 Set @rs= RetrieveSalesforceObjects('Opportunity', 'Id, Name,StageName,CaseSafeID__c', 'CaseSafeID__c', '=', '_subscriberkey')
 Set @Opprow = ROW(@rs,1)
 Set @Oppname = FIELD(@Opprow ,"Name") 
 ]%%

 %%=v(@Oppname)=%% //to print opportunity name
```

Comment: Did you check the query in Salesforce. Your query should have returned more than one record and the first record name is displayed in the template.